# Remove specific inline style with jquery

Tags: jquery, css, inline-styles

There's an asp menu I'm using that is auto inserting style="width:3px;" into my menu table tds creating a nasty gab in between my tabs. I'm testing to remove this inline style with jquery instead of our developer customizing the menu just for this cosmetic blemish.

below is a simple example:

```
<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
   <tr>
      <td style="width:3px;">hello world</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

in jquery, i can remove all tds with the style attribute by doing:

```
$('td').removeAttr('style');
```

so, my question is, how can i target the inline style that only contains 3px?

Here's my live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/n9upF/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are asking how you can select td's that have style attribute with only `width:3px;` in it, right?

You can use **[Attribute Equals Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)**.

```
$("td[style='width:3px;']").removeAttr("style");​
```

Comment: Can this work just by style type? I'm trying to remove all occurrences of font-family and font-size, but I don't know the value of them.

Comment: @TomHart - you can use something like "starts with" or contains (see all options for jQuery attribute selectors [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/).  For example, `$("div[style*='font-family'], div[style*='font-size']")`.  Note that this is an exact match, so if someone used shorthand, for example, `background: red url(http://lorempixel/200/100) no-repeat;` you would not be able to pick up `background-image` since it was not used in the value of the style attribute.

Answer (score 8):

I believe that Evan wanted to remove only the width:3px;  from the style while the other css styling remain in the attribute. So here is the solution:

```
$('td').each(function(){
  if ($(this).attr('style').indexOf('3px') !== -1){
    var style = $(this).attr('style');
      $(this).attr('style', style.replace(/width: ?3px;/g, ''));
  }
});
```

Working example is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jRptd/)

If this is not what you needed then the Sarfraz is shown the proper solution. :)

Comment: nik - thank you for your help! i found Brian's seem to do the trick with a little less code, while yours addressed my question with more effort after Sarfaz started the code. again, i appreciate your help.

Comment: My solution would work if you want to remove only the width and keep the other styling. If you just want to remove the style attribute completely the solution of Brian is the shortest indeed. Although It didn't work for me. Anyway :)

Comment: Saved my bacon bro. Viva la Southend!

Comment: Nice answer! Helped for my case, too. Curiosity: What is the -- /width: ?3px;/g -- g for?

Comment: Actually not needed, since in style it's not possible to have more than one width. Here is explanation for global modifier - http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_g.asp

Answer (score 4):

> so, my question is, how can i only
>   target the inline style that contains
>   only 3px?

Try this:

```
$('td').each(function(){
  if ($(this).attr('style').indexOf('3px') !== -1){
    $(this).removeAttr('style');
  }
});
```

[See Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/n9upF/4/)